# Can I use sed to rename files with a "running count"?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a directory full of pictures. Lets say

```
/usr/pics/foo 
/usr/pics/duckface.jpg 
usr/pics/bar.bmp 
...
```

I'd like to go through and rename them to

```
/usr/pics/pic1 
/usr/pics/pic2 
/usr/pics/pic3 
...
```

Doesn't have to be `sed` anything I can run from a `bash` script will be fine. I think I can handle the regex I just don't know what to replace with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that all files in the directory are images and you want to rename all of them without worrying of extensions or file types. Then try:

```
for f in /usr/pics/*; do ((i++)); mv "$f" "${f%/*}/pic${i}"; done
```

Comment: +1 but you should probably put make it `mv -- ...` since the file names don't seem to follow any pattern so MAYBE there'd be one that starts with a minus.

Comment: @EdMorton: I thought it but it's not needed when using absolute paths (tested).

Comment: Thanks that's super simple and much easier to read than some of the sed commands I had been stringing together.

Comment: @Birei - ah, you're right, I didn't notice that. Sorry for the noise!